# Azure devops complains about the syntax loop

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have some problems with syntax, but it looks good. I can't find the mistake

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

parameters:
  - name: themeNames
    values:
      - '1'
      - '2'
      - '3'

stages:
- stage: dev
  displayName: Dev
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
    - ${{ each parameter in parameters.themeNames }}:
      - template: build.yml
        parameters:
          themeName: ${{ parameter }}
```

what is wrong?
[image]

now I use a solution like this, but I don't like it

> stages:
>
> - stage: dev   displayName: Dev   jobs:
>
>   - job: Deploy
>     steps:
>
>     - template: build.yml
>       parameters:
>       themeName: '1'
>     - template: build.yml
>       parameters:
>       themeName: '2'
>     - template: build.yml
>       parameters:
>       themeName: '3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: run pipe with one parameter is to use a type object.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

parameters:
- name: themeNames1
  type: object
  default: 
   - 1
   - 2
   - 3


stages:
- stage: dev
  displayName: Dev
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
    - ${{ each parameter in parameters.themeNames1 }}:
      - bash: echo " ${{ parameter }}"
```

[image]

It works properly but ADO still complains about syntax. But if save it and run. It works...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please divide the value of themeNames into three different parameters. Otherwise, themeNames has only one value when you run the pipeline. Here is my sample:

**azure-pipelines.yml**:

```
parameters:
- name: themeNames1
  default: 1
- name: themeNames2
  default: 2
- name: themeNames3
  default: 3


stages:
- stage: dev
  displayName: Dev
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
    - ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
      - template: build.yml
        parameters: 
          themeName: ${{ parameter.value }}
```

**build.yml**:

```
parameters:
- name: themeName
  default: ''
steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.themeName }}
```

**Result:**

[image]

You can also refer to the document about [loop through parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters) and [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).